# Angular 6 Schematics Invalid Source (undefined)

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I'm creating some custom schematics that will help us spin up angular library projects quickly.  Given that, I don't want developers to have to have a checklist of `ng ...` commands they have to run to get a library up and running, I'd like to just have a single command that sets up a workspace, puts a library in it, makes some customizations (swap in jest for karma, add some CI config, etc).

My approach in doing this is to create a schematic that starts with an empty tree, then calls the `ng-new` schematic from `@schematics/angular`, via `externalSchematic()` then chains the `library` schematic from the same package followed by a number of our custom schematics to make the customizations.

My reasons for wanting to use `externalSchematic()` as opposed to just copying all the external schematics' code into my schematics project is so that when `@schematics/angular` is updated, I can incorporate those updates by just doing `yarn upgrade-interactive` and find and resolve any issues by running the test suite.  Eventually we can automate this with CI.

I've created a small self contained example reproducing my error here: https://github.com/matt328/ng-schematics-test

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone
npm install
npm run build
schematics ng-schematics-test:my-full-schematic --name=test-schematic
```

When I run the schematic, it reports `Invalid source: undefined.`

Here

https://github.com/matt328/ng-schematics-test/blob/master/src/my-full-schematic/index.ts#L30

is where I'm using `externalSchematic()` to call `ng-new`.

I've did some digging into the source and found it is caused by a few of the angular schematics' having

```
"$default": {
  "$source": "projectName"
}
```

in their schemas.  The error is a result of `projectName` not being defined.

What else has to be done in order to be able to call `ng-new` with `externalSchema()`?  Is this approach valid, or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Back in early February I was able to get a working version of the `externalSchematics` command from this [demo working](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2). When I tried to replicate my previous results today, I received the same error as you (for `ng-new`, `component`, and `interface` when I tried to run the command from within the schematics project.

However, when I created a new Angular project and created a symlink to the schematic project, I was able to successfully generate a `component` and `interface` in the Angular project. Have not yet succeeded with `ng-new` since the `node_modules` mapping isn't quite as simple (it did prompt me for some required parameters, `version` and `name` before throwing a missing module error, which I suppose may be construed as progress).

Comment: Hey @ericksoen! Can you, plese, share your dependencies from the new project? Even working with a fresh installed environment it still not working. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [repo link to a paired down version of my schematic project](https://github.com/ericksoen/schematic-demo). It has a single passing test for a `ng-new` command.

I also validated that if you create a symlink to the project root, that you can use it to initialize new projects using `ng new project-name --collection demo-schematic`

Answer (score 1):

This one took me a while:

It seems that you **must** run **any schematic that extends an `@schematics/angular` schematic** inside an real angular project. To do so, do the following:

- `$ cd <path to an angular project>`
- `$ npm link <path to your custom schematics project>`
- `$ ng g <schematics-collection-name>:<schematic-name> [params]`

this should work, as your extended @schematics/angular schematic now runs inside an angular project and is able to get a correct source.

**Also note:** Running it with `$ schematics <collection-name>:<schematics-name>` will lead to the same undefined error!

Hope this helps